# Capture ALL WebAPI requests

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-web-api

I would like to capture and save in a log file all the requests that my WebAPI should handle.

Just tried to save the Request.Content from the controller constructor but unfortunately, 
the request object is null from the controller constructor scope.

Hope to learn an efficient way to do it.

Comment: you can use tools like `log4net` or `Elmah` for logging request and response

Comment: Thanks, I am looking for native solution without using external utils.

Answer (score 2):

I would just hook into web api tracing...

http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/testing-and-debugging/tracing-in-aspnet-web-api

From the above article, you can implement ITraceWriter like so. This example uses System.Diagnostics.Trace.WriteLine, but you could plug in writing to a file here as well.

```
public class SimpleTracer : ITraceWriter
{
    public void Trace(HttpRequestMessage request, string category, TraceLevel level, 
        Action<TraceRecord> traceAction)
    {
        TraceRecord rec = new TraceRecord(request, category, level);
        traceAction(rec);
        WriteTrace(rec);
    }

    protected void WriteTrace(TraceRecord rec)
    {
        var message = string.Format("{0};{1};{2}", 
            rec.Operator, rec.Operation, rec.Message);
        System.Diagnostics.Trace.WriteLine(message, rec.Category);
    }
}
```

As you can see from the Trace method, you get access to the HttpRequestMessage here.

Answer (score 1):

I ended up implementing middleware to deal with it.

```
public class GlobalRequestLogger : OwinMiddleware
{
   public override Task Invoke(IOwinContext context)
   {
      // Implement logging code here
   }
}
```

Then in your Startup.cs:

```
app.Use<GlobalRequestLogger>();
```

Comment: Using OWIN pointed me in the right direction. You could have explained a bit more, like how to create and configure the Startup class and that  await this.Next.Invoke(context); would be necessary in the overridden Invoke method. Thanks anyway.